# Creating multiple CSS files from Less based on static variables

Tags: css, less, right-to-left, direction

I'm looking to create an internationalised application which will support Right To Left content.

Therefore standard (LTR) would be:

```
div{
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Whereas RTL would be:

```
div{
   padding-right:10px;
}
```

Using Less I could do:

```
@left:right;

.div{
    padding-@{left}:10px;
}
```

Which would produce:

```
.div {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Is there a way of producing two CSS files for when `@left = right` and `@left = left`?

For example I could have:

> Styles.less

Which produces:

> Styles.css
>
> Styles.rtl.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this file  name will be **styles-rtl.less**

```
@import "styles.less";

/*override variables */

@direction          :ltr;
@oposite-direction  :rtl;

@start-direction    :left;
@end-direction      :right;

@tr-direction       :-1;/*for manipulation transform*/
```

Example for using:

```
/*positions*/
position:absolute;

right:0;    
/*will be*/    
@{start-direction}:0;

/**************/

float:right;    
/*will be*/    
float:@start-direction;


/**************/
direction:rtl;    
/*will be*/
direction:@direction;

/*************/
transform:translateX(180px);
/*will be*/
transform:translateX(180px*@tr-direction);/*multiple by minus*/
```

Comment: Thanks, how does this produce multiple CSS files? Are you suggesting I need to have duplicate LESS files importing `styles.less` in one and `styles-rtl.less` on the other?

Comment: Actually I understand now - we'd have an override less file which imports the original less file, perfect, cheers!